# opencv 3: CVcreatebutton gives LNK2019 error

Tags: c, opencv3.0

I started learning about using opencv 3 in c. While I was learning about the highgui.h functions, I tried to use the function cvCreateButton and I

got the following error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvCreateButton referenced in function _main

I also got:

> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I am using visual studio 2013, on a windows 10 laptop
Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core_c.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,sliderVal = 0;
    cvNamedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window
    //create an image
    IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/magshimim/Pictures/py.png", 1);
    cvCreateTrackbar("test", "Display window", &sliderVal, 500, NULL);//trackbar without name
    CvScalar color = { 0 };
    color.val[3] = 255;//alpha value of 255
    //make the square exactly in the middle of the picture
    CvPoint p1 = cvPoint(image->width / 4, image->height / 4);//top left quarter of image
    CvPoint p2 = cvPoint(p1.x * 3, p1.y * 3);//botton right quarter of image

    cvCreateButton("button", NULL, "button", CV_PUSH_BUTTON, 0);//that is the line that gives the error

    srand(time(NULL));//random seed
    if (!image)//The image is empty.
    {
        printf("could not open image\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                color.val[i] = rand() % 256;//random color for square
            }
            //add square on picture, and update the screen
            cvRectangle(image, p1, p2, color, -1, 0, 0);
            cvShowImage("Display window", image);
            cvWaitKey(sliderVal + 1);//slider sets the delay between each color change, delay of 0 is to wait forever so minimum delay is 1


        }

        cvWaitKey(0);


        system("pause");
        cvReleaseImage(&image);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the project properties, I added in **C/C++->general->Additional** Include directories the folder with all the include files `(opencv\build\include)`

And in the linker, in **general->additonal** library directories i added `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin and C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib`

And in input->additional dependencies I added `opencv_world300d.lib` and `opencv_ts300d.lib`.

I got the instructions from my c teacher, in a after school class/activity about programming in c. The instructions are in Hebrew, but here is the link if anyone wants to look

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxa6_LIMELY4RjVvVDJGZkNRZ1k

I downloaded opencv from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.0.0/opencv-3.0.0.exe/download.

Even if I add `opencv_highgui300d.lib` to linker->input->additional dependencies it doesn't solve the problem.
How can I solve it?
And what caused the error?
Noam Wiseman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add opencv/bin/Release opendcv/bin/Debug to your path - you'll need to include the **full** path, with quotes if you have spaces in the path name. An alternative is to copy the needed dlls to your solution's Release and Debug folders.  The dlls have the same base name as the libraries you included in your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to say that I already added opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin to the path.What is the FILL path?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo I meant FULL.

Comment: I ended up copying the dlls one by one to my project build folders.

Comment: which dlls did you copy? I only found opencv_ffmpeg300.dll,opencv_world300.dll and opencv_world300d.dll. And where did you copy them? To the directory debug in the project folder?

Comment: I have opencv_core320.dll opencv_imgcodecs320.dll opencv_imgproc320.dll opencv_videoio320.dll and the same ending with *320d.dll as well. in both debug and release folder where my executables are.

Comment: I got them from my opencv\bin\Debug and opencv\bin\Release

Comment: @noamwiseman  Hi I posted this a few days ago, there is a bug in the opencv 3.2 setup and opencv_world320.dll does not build for windows 32.  the post describes how I built opencv, maybe this will help.

Comment: which version of opencv did you try? I am using version 3.0.0. I thought that maybe trying version 3.2.0  would help, but instead I have more LNK2019 errors(for all opencv functions). Where can I find the post that explains how to build opencv?

Comment: I use openvc 3.2.  I was quite cetain I had posted the link on using cmake-gui, but cannot see it.  Here it is again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533851/opencv-exe-system-error/44534558#44534558.  As a last resort, maybe you can change the output folder of your app, so that it will put your executables in your opencv/bin/Debug and /Release folders.

Comment: when you say opencv/bin/debug and /Release folders, do you mean the folders in the visual studio project?

Comment: Oh wait, after the build I found the bin/debug and release folders. In the original download, there is only a bin folder with opencv_ffmpeg320.dll and opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll file. After I to cmake all functions, like you explained in your post. When I ran the highgui test with createbutton function is threw an exception, that it needs QT support. And I dont want to use QT. I will use another approach to make a button: on a mouse event, look at mouse coordinates and decide.I will mark your answer as the way to find my solution, Thanks for your help